# How to find path with highest sum in a weighted networkx graph?

Tags: python, networkx

I have a directed networkx weighted graph. How do I find the path with the biggest sum of weights?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`all_simple_paths`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html) and check the maximum. Assuming you have a function that takes a path and gives you the sum of the weights:

```
heaviest_path = max((path for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source, dest)),
                    key=lambda path: get_weight(path))
```

In case two of them have the same weight, this will give you the first one found.

Comment: There are no complaints so far but for me, I needed to put the generator expression in additional parentheses. ->
`max((path for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source, dest)),...`

Comment: @peer thanks for noticing, I have edited it. I believe that was allowed in older versions of Python, or most likely, I didn't test it (since i don't have a `get_weight`).