# How to find the longest path with Python NetworkX?

Tags: python, networkx

I have a directed graph from S to T.

And I would like to find the route (S, A, C, E, T) and the sum of its capacities (1 + 2 + 3 + 1 = 7) so the sum is the largest.

I tried networkx.algorithms.flow.ford_fulkerson, but I don't know how to get the one-way direction from S to T.

My environment:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Python 2.7.8
- NetworkX 1.9
- Matplotlib 1.4.0

example.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pylab as p
import networkx as nx

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DG = nx.DiGraph()
    DG.add_edge('S', 'a', capacity=1)
    DG.add_edge('a', 'b', capacity=1)
    DG.add_edge('a', 'c', capacity=2)
    DG.add_edge('b', 'd', capacity=1)
    DG.add_edge('b', 'e', capacity=2)
    DG.add_edge('c', 'e', capacity=3)
    DG.add_edge('c', 'f', capacity=2)
    DG.add_edge('d', 'T', capacity=1)
    DG.add_edge('e', 'T', capacity=1)
    DG.add_edge('f', 'T', capacity=1)

    result = nx.algorithms.flow.ford_fulkerson(DG, 'S', 'T')
    print(result.size(weight='capacity')) # 15.0, but I want 7.

    pos = nx.spectral_layout(DG)
    nx.draw(DG, pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(DG, pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(DG, pos)
    p.show()

    # This shows a partly bidirectional graph, which is not what I want.
    pos = nx.spectral_layout(result)
    nx.draw(result, pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(result, pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(result, pos)
    p.show()
```

Comment: Maximum flow doesn't work like that. The flow doesn't take a single route, and the capacities don't add like that. Are you sure you know what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm new to graph theory and NetworkX. I just would like to find the way from S to T with the largest sum of capacities, and I thought NetworkX might help.

Comment: That's the [longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), not maximum flow.

Answer (score 4):

Using negative weight often doesn't work for Dijkstra algorithm.
This error `ValueError: ('Contradictory paths found:', 'negative weights?')` will show up.

It should distinguish the problem of "Longest Path" and the "Maximum Sum Path".

The answer here: [How to find path with highest sum in a weighted networkx graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008252/how-to-find-path-with-highest-sum-in-a-weighted-networkx-graph), that uses [all_simple_paths](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html?highlight=all_simple_paths).

Note that in the function `all_simple_paths(G, source, target, cutoff=None)`, using `cutoff` param (integer number) can help to limit the depth of search from `source` to `target`. It also controls the length of the path that we want to find.

Answer (score 2):

The negative weights works for johnson. In your case, modified as:

```
DG = nx.DiGraph()
DG.add_edge('S', 'a', weight=-1)
DG.add_edge('a', 'b', weight=-1)
DG.add_edge('a', 'c', weight=-2)
DG.add_edge('b', 'd', weight=-1)
DG.add_edge('b', 'e', weight=-2)
DG.add_edge('c', 'e', weight=-3)
DG.add_edge('c', 'f', weight=-2)
DG.add_edge('d', 'T', weight=-1)
DG.add_edge('e', 'T', weight=-1)
DG.add_edge('f', 'T', weight=-1)
```

To find longest path, get the one-way direction from S to T with

```
p2 = nx.johnson (DG, weight='weight')
print('johnson: {0}'.format(p2['S']['T']))
```

result as: `johnson: ['S', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'T']`

My environment:

- Software Version
- Python   3.4.5 64bit [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
- IPython  5.1.0 OS    Windows 10 10.0.14393
- networkx 1.11

[Networkx 1.11 docs for johnson](https://networkx.org/documentation//networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.johnson.html)

[Networkx 3.21 docs for johnson](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.johnson.html#johnson)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import networkx as nx

def inverse_weight(graph, weight='weight'):
    copy_graph = graph.copy()
    for n, eds in copy_graph.adjacency_iter():
        for ed, eattr in eds.items():
            copy_graph[n][ed][weight] = eattr[weight] * -1
    return copy_graph

def longest_path_and_length(graph, s, t, weight='weight'):
    i_w_graph = inverse_weight(graph, weight)
    path = nx.dijkstra_path(i_w_graph, s, t)
    length = nx.dijkstra_path_length(i_w_graph, s, t) * -1
    return path, length

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DG = nx.DiGraph()
    DG.add_edge('S', 'a', weight=1)
    DG.add_edge('a', 'b', weight=1)
    DG.add_edge('a', 'c', weight=2)
    DG.add_edge('b', 'd', weight=1)
    DG.add_edge('b', 'e', weight=2)
    DG.add_edge('c', 'e', weight=3)
    DG.add_edge('c', 'f', weight=2)
    DG.add_edge('d', 'T', weight=1)
    DG.add_edge('e', 'T', weight=1)
    DG.add_edge('f', 'T', weight=1)

    print(longest_path_and_length(DG, 'S', 'T')) # (['S', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'T'], 7)
```

Comment: That isn't going to work in general. If you have a DAG you can use the algorithm here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985202/networkx-efficiently-find-absolute-longest-path-in-digraph

Comment: Also, you may use [`all_simple_paths`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html).