# Find Longest Weighted Path from DAG with Networkx in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, weighted, longest-path

I need a algorithm for find the longest weighted path in a directed, acyclic graph `networkx.MultiDiGraph()`. My graph has weighted edges and many edges have a null value as the weighting. In networkx doc I have found nothing for solve this problem. My graph has the following structure:

```
>>> print graph.nodes()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 25, 26, 'end']
>>> print graph.edges()
[(0, 'end'), (1, 0), (1, 10), (1, 5), (2, 1), (2, 11), (2, 6), (3, 2), (3, 12), (3, 7), (4, 8), (4, 3), (4, 13), (5, 'end'), (6, 5), (6, 15), (7, 16), (7, 6), (8, 17), (8, 7), (10, 'end'), (11, 10), (11, 20), (11, 15), (12, 16), (12, 11), (12, 21), (13, 17), (13, 12), (13, 22), (15, 'end'), (16, 25), (16, 15), (17, 16), (17, 26), (20, 'end'), (21, 25), (21, 20), (22, 26), (22, 21), (25, 'end'), (26, 25)]
>>> print graph.edge[7][16]
{1: {'weight': 100.0, 'time': 2}}
>>> print graph.edge[7][6]
{0: {'weight': 0, 'time': 2}}
```

I find this her, but I have problems with the implementation:

1. [networkx: efficiently find absolute longest path in digraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985202/networkx-efficiently-find-absolute-longest-path-in-digraph) this solution is without weightings.
2. [How to find the longest path with Python NetworkX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589633/how-to-find-the-longest-path-with-python-networkx) This solution transformed the weightings into negativ values, but my graph has null values… and the `nx.dijkstra_path()` does not support negative values.

Have anyone an idea or a solution to a similar problem found?

Comment: if `nx.dijkstra_path()` does not support negative weights, transform weights according to `w  <--  -w + Wmax` where `Wmax` is the maximum weight in the original graph.

Comment: This does not work because the algorithm continues the shortest path searching… Or I understand this wrong?

Comment: This does not work because the weight change for each path will depend on the number of edges.

Answer (score 0):

Take the solution in the link `1` and change the line:

```
pairs = [[dist[v][0]+1,v] for v in G.pred[node]] # incoming pairs
```

To something like:

```
pairs = [[dist[v][0]+edge['weight'],v] for u, edge in G[v][node] for v in G.pred[node]] # incoming pairs
```