# Find shortest and longest weights from one to another using NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I want to compute all possible values(column in csv) for a particular source to destination. I was able to create a graph using the following code :

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Rates.csv')

Graphtype = nx.MultiDiGraph()

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Source', target='Destination', edge_attr='value',create_using=Graphtype)   



# print all paths 

for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source='a', target='d'):
    print(path)
```

I am getting the output correctly for a particular source to destination.

**Output**

```
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    ['a', 'b', 'd']
    ['a', 'd']
    ['a', 'c', 'd']
```

Since, we have assigned the weights to the graph as well, I want to calculate the weights for all the paths as well. i.e for lets say ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] the weight would be SUM(a->b,b->c,c->d) and same for all the paths.

Is there any way that I can achieve the same using networkX. I was able to take a look into the documentation

> https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/weighted.html

But it only talks about the shortest path for a particular source to destination. The primary aim is to calculate the minimum weight and maximum weight from a particular source to destination. Is there a way to achieve the same.

We can achieve the same by creation of the function, thanks to

> [How to find path with highest sum in a weighted networkx graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008252/how-to-find-path-with-highest-sum-in-a-weighted-networkx-graph/24009190#24009190)

```
heaviest_path = max((path for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source, dest)),
                    key=lambda path: get_weight(path))
```

Can anyone advise as to how can we build the get_weight function.

**EDIT**:

The G.edges() provides the output :

```
OutMultiEdgeDataView([('a', 'b', {'value': 0.7}), ('a', 'd', {'value': 0.52}), ('a', 'c', {'value': 0.33}), ('b', 'c', {'value': 0.58}), ('b', 'd', {'value': 0.66}), ('c', 'd', {'value': 0.4}), ('d', 'b', {'value': 0.3})])
```

where value would be the weight.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe anything is built in to networkx.  But I think it's a fairly simple function to write.  I'm going to assume the weight is stored in the edge attribute `'weight'`.

```
def get_weight(G, path):
    total = 0
    for u, v in zip(path[:-1], path[1:]):
        total += G.edges[u,v]['weight']
    return total
```

I used `zip` which will take two lists and return pairs made up of the first elements of its arguments, then the second elements, then the third etc.  I passed into `zip` two lists, the first list is `path`, but without its last element.  The second list is `path` but without its first element.  So if `path = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, then the first thing `zip` returns is `('a','b')`.  The next thing is `('b', 'c')`, etc.

You could make this a bit more compact by using something like a list comprehension:

```
def get_weight(G, path):
    return sum(G.edges[u,v]['weight'] for u,v in zip(path[:-1], path[1:]))
```

I believe it's also a bit faster, but I might be wrong on that.  It's unlikely to make a significant difference unless you're doing many of these calculations.

Comment: Thank you for your response, 
 I tried this :

`G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Source', target='Destination', edge_attr='value',create_using=Graphtype)

heaviest_path = max((path for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, 'a', 'd')),
                    key=lambda path: get_weight(G,path))

def get_weight(G, path):
    return sum(G.edges[u,v]['value'] for u,v in zip(path[:-1], path[1:]))`

It returns me with the error : **ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)**. Any reason as to why this error.

Comment: G.edges.data() returns me the output : `Out[90]: OutMultiEdgeDataView([('a', 'b', {'value': 0.7}), ('a', 'd', {'value': 0.52}), ('a', 'c', {'value': 0.33}), ('b', 'c', {'value': 0.58}), ('b', 'd', {'value': 0.66}), ('c', 'd', {'value': 0.4}), ('d', 'b', {'value': 0.3})])`
where value is supposed to be the weight

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using the following code :

```
def get_weight(G, path):
    total = 0
    for u, v in zip(path[:-1], path[1:]):
        total += G.get_edge_data(u,v)[0]['value']
    return total
```

Thanks to @Joel for helping out in understanding the same.